# How to divide an array into multiples of 2 php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to divide an array into a multiple-dimensional array with 2 'elements' in each contained array.

So far I've only been able to divide them into a specified number of chunks, but as the number of elements are determined from a foreach loop and call to the database, I'm struggling to divide them into multiples of 2.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key)
{
    $data[] = $key;
}

echo '<pre>';
  print_r(partition($data, $i));
echo '</pre>';



function partition(Array $list, $p) 
{
  $listlen = count($list);
  $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
  $partrem = $listlen % $p;
  $partition = array();
  $mark = 0;

  for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++)
  {
    $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
    $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
    $mark += $incr;
  }

  return $partition;
}
```

The desired output would be like this ...

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
     [0] => img.jpg
     [1] => http://google.com
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
     [0] => img.jpg
     [1] => http://google.com
  )
  [2] => Array
  (
     [0] => img.jpg
     [1] => http://google.com
  )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: it would be useful if you added a simple example of at least the expected result

Comment: Apologies. I've added an example of the desired output

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function (-;

Example:

```
<?php
print_r(array_chunk($data, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

see below solution:

```
foreach (range(1, 10) as $key)
{
    $data[] = $key;
}
$i = 2;
echo '<pre>';
print_r(partition($data, $i));
echo '</pre>';

function partition(Array $list, $p)
{
    $partition = array_chunk($list, $p, true);

    return $partition;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [8] => 9
            [9] => 10
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) does this for you.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key)
{
    $data[] = $key;
}
var_dump(array_chunk($data, 2));
```